# How to keep transparency on fullscreen windows?

Tags: macos, graphics, fullscreen, emacs

I'm trying to put Emacs in transparency mode. It works, but only when its window is not on fullscreen mode:

[image: Transparent]

But as soon as I fullscreen the window, it breaks it :

[image: Non-transparent]

The reason I'm posting this here and not in the Emacs stack exchange is because it does the same with other apps such as Terminal. I think it's a macOS thing that I would like to change. Some ideas?

Comment: The whole point of Full Screen is that one window fills the screen. There are no 'other windows' behind it.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I have to remove the dock then, because if it's here I can't get the height I wish I had in fullscreen. I really thought it would be something else, but ok. Thanks.

Comment: The Dock does not appear in Full Screen mode (for me, testing TextEdit).